# Fit Screen Android WebApp (avoid horizontal Scroll)

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, web-applications

i'm trying to fix an issue in my web app, i want to avoid the horizontal scrolling (only aloows the scrool down-up)

I add this tag to avoid it in IOS Browser and work fine, but not in Android browsers...

```
<meta name = "Viewport" content = "maximum-scale=1, width=device-width,  maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0" >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your body has width 100%, and that no child has a fixed width higher than the screen horizontal resolution.

Other than that, this meta tag in the header should be enough:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Comment: i think doesn work on a web app html based, is more like for a native app, right?

Comment: i think so, have you tried to resize your webview to matchparent intead wrap content?

Comment: well, no, i didnt tried with that, is a normal website designed to fix under 320px, nothing else, but for any reason if you scroll it to theleft or the right it drags all the page i want to avoid that.